# Spring Bean for setting up a connectionFactory to a JBoss HornetQ

Tags: spring, jboss, jms, hornetq

I'm taking an application that currently outputs to ActiveMQ, and repointing it to use a JBoss HornetQ that has been set up for me. The application is a standalone one (does not run within a EJB container), and uses Spring 2 (although I have updated to Spring 3 to get access to the 'name' attribute).

I've refered to examples, which come out as:

```
<bean name="connectionFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="ha" value="false"/>
    <constructor-arg name="initialConnectors">
        <bean name="transportConfiguration" class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
            <constructor-arg name="className" value="org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory" />
            <constructor-arg name="params">
                <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
                    <entry key="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
                    <entry key="port" value="5445" />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Using this gives the exception

```
  "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean     failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not     instantiate bean class [org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
```

I am matching the constructor "public HornetQJMSConnectionFactory(boolean ha, org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration... initialConnectors)" (Taken from the class file in the jboss-client.jar file I'm using) as far as I can see.

I also seem to be matching the constructor for the TransportConfiguration, which is "public TransportConfiguration(java.lang.String className, java.util.Map params)"

So, can anyone kindly point out what I am doing wrong here? I've a feeling it's going to be something stupid :)

I've tried appending the type onto everything as follows, but still get the same thing:

```
<bean name="connectionFactory" class="org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQJMSConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="ha" value="false" type="boolean"/>
    <constructor-arg name="initialConnectors" type="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration[]">
        <bean name="transportConfiguration" class="org.hornetq.api.core.TransportConfiguration">
            <constructor-arg name="className" value="org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <constructor-arg name="params" type="java.util.Map">
                <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Object">
                    <entry key="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
                    <entry key="port" value="5445" />
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better using jndi nad only depend on jms (not hornetq).

1- Define a connection-factory in standalone.xml in Jboss:

```
<connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
    <connectors>
    <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
    </connectors>
    <entries>
        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/ConnectionFactory"/>
    </entries>
</connection-factory>
```

2- Define a connection-factory bean using jndi:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/jboss/exported/jms/ConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

So you are only depend on jms-api and in the future you can change your jms-broker easily whenever you want:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This would have worked, however the application is not running in a J2EE server context so it complains about the java: prefix and anything else I put in brought back a 'not found' error for the queue. 

I wound up creating a test java class for the connection with much logging, and still got the same error. Turned out to be a third party JAR file that needed updated.

Comment: Yes, the java: prefix is for jboss. But the idea was using jndi and depending only on jms api, not hornetq artifacts.